# How to parse json data between json with uppercase to class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

From PHP server, I receive a json data
and using class in Flutter I want to transfer the data to class.
But because uppercase or hyphen character I can't parse from json data to class type.
Maybe that is inconsistency problem between php json data and class.
But I can't use uppercase or hyphen character in class of Flutter.
How to resolve this?

**Received data from PHP**
     `{reset: true, SESSIONID: 230hnoco0lnao6da7gqd9t5i56, chat_nations:.....}

**Defined class in Flutter **

```
class Post {
String id,  sessionid;
bool error,  reset;
List<ChatNation> chatNations = [];

Post({
    this.reset,
    this.sessionid,
    List<ChatNation> chatNations,
    this.error,
    this.id,              
});

factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PostFromJson(json);
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PostToJson(this);
```

}

**Result in defined class**

```
{"id":null,"sessionid":null,"error":false,"reset":true,"chatNations":[]}
```

Comment: the response is not a valid JSON. Please ask your PHP dev to send valid JSON in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JSON Returned from PHP service is wrong. SESSIONID is a string, so it must be enclosed in "double quotes"
2. Dart `json_annotation` has `JsonKey` annotation which can take optional name for JSON key. So you can re-write class `Post` as

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Post {

@JsonKey(nullable: true)
String id;

@JsonKey(nullable: false, name="SESSIONID")
String sessionid;

....
}
```

Check the documentation of `JsonKey` annotation.

However, this approach has a problem: JSON generated by DART will also have these incosistent names/keys.

If you want to fix this, better you write your own implementatino of `fromJson` to e.g.

```
Post fromJson(Map json) => Post({
sessionid: (json['sessionid'] ?? json['SESSIONID']) as String,
id: json[id],
....
});
```

Comment: This is the answer I want. Thank you for reply